# Can't install Laravel on Synology NAS (DSM 6) due to missing PHP extension

Tags: laravel, synology

I'm trying to install Laravel on Web Station in my Synology NAS with DSM 6. After installing composer I run the command `composer create-project laravel/laravel web-project` but all I got is this error.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.3.0 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.1 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.10 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.11 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.12 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.13 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.14 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.15 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.16 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.17 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.18 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.2 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.3 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.4 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.5 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.6 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.7 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.8 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v5.3.9 requires classpreloader/classpreloader ~3.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[3.0.0].
    - classpreloader/classpreloader 3.0.0 requires nikic/php-parser ^1.0|^2.0 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.2.2, v1.3.0, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.1.0, v2.1.1].
    - nikic/php-parser v2.1.1 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v2.1.0 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v2.0.1 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v2.0.0 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.4.1 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.4.0 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.3.0 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.2.2 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.2.1 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.2.0 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.1.0 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.0.2 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.0.1 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - nikic/php-parser v1.0.0 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.0, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16, v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.2, v5.3.3, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.3.6, v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.9].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Also checked my Web Station config and saw that the tokenizer extension is missing but I see no option to install it.

[image]

So, my question is: **How can I add the tokenizer extension to PHP on my Synology NAS?** 
PHP version is 5.6.

Thanks

Comment: Does this allows you to have access via cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use php56 instead of php command.
Exemple:  php56 composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel theproject "5.2.*"

Comment: That's not a problem related to the version, neither php and laravel. To install laravel it requires you to have some php extensions, which he apparently dont have.

Comment: Actually, this made the deal. Using php56 instead of php allowed me to create a Laravel project. Seems that Synology NAS has two different versions of PHP and just the one use with the php56 command hast the necessary extensions. Thanks :)

Comment: Important. You have to install composer as part of your system in /usr/local/bin

Answer (score -1):

run `composer self-update` then try to create a project in a new folder.

and it fails, you can change the laravel version to one below for example `composer create-project laravel/laravel web-project "5.2.*"`

Comment: It keeps failing, even with Laravel 5.2.

Comment: if you have a xampp o mamp to develop web apps, uninstall it and download again one of them and then install again, i think is missing some  archives from the installation of the php.

Comment: That's not a problem with composer, its with his php modules. He needs to somehow access the command line or the interface on his synology which allows him to install missing modules. For what i've searched, he can access it with ikpg (how to get access to it? i dont know...).